# What is the proper way to set up the front page?

Tags: 7

I currently have my front page set to a node/basic page through *Configuration > Site information > Default front page*. Will this cause Google to index both the home page and the default front page? I just don't want to get hit for duplicate content.

I’m worried because both were showing on the XML sitemap before I removed the default front page (droneswithcameras.com/search-best-drones-cameras). You can look at my site to see what I’m talking about. The default homepage is set to /search-best-drones-cameras.

Are the front page and home page essentially the same thing? It’s just strange to me that there are multiple URLs for the same page.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 you can disable the /node route by disabling the view called "Frontpage", effectively eliminating the frontpage concept.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified I am using Drupal 7